# Passing input data from view to controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Hello I'm new to MVC and AJAX.
I have a problem sending input data from view to controller.
What is the wrong thing in this code ? :
Thanks in advance.

**Head** :

> `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

**View :**

```
<div id="inputdiv">
    <p>Display name: <input type="text" id="name1" /> </p>
    <p><button id="submitbutton">Submit</button></p>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(function () {

        $("#submitbutton").click(function () {

            var nameEntered = $("#name1").val()

            $.post(
                '<%= Url.Action("SimplePost") %>',
                { submittedName: nameEntered },
                handleSuccess
            );

        });

    });

    function handleSuccess(content) {
        $("#inputdiv").html(content);
        $("#inputdiv").addClass("easy-notification");
    }
</script>
```

**Controller :**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ContentResult SimplePost(string submittedName)
    {
        string result = string.Format("Hello {0}!?", submittedName);
        return new ContentResult { Content = result };
    }
```

Comment: Have you done any debugging? Check for javascript errors, check that the request looks right, step through the server-side code and make sure the action is getting hit and the model binding worked, check the response, and check the value of `content`.

Comment: `success: handleSuccess` -- you still have to specify `success` in your AJAX config

Comment: Thank you all very much for your help. 

I have tried debugging in server-side code. And get this error in Console : "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)."

The main problem is, the action and my breakpoint is not getting hit.

Comment: Using F12 in your browser will help you to debug the javascript call. The code has minor errors (; over there, ad catch success as told above). Good luck.

Comment: Thank you, I have checked with F12 as you say and getting that error, unfortinately.